# Image size with respect to pixels

Tags: matlab, graphics

I want to increase the image size with respect to pixels, that is a image of size 150x225  should be changed to 250x250. How can I do that in Matlab?

Comment: I'm moving your question to StackOverflow. As already mentioned, the site you posted on is for *Mathematica*, not MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matlab function `imresize`.

e.g. `B = imresize(A, [250 250]);`
where `A` is your initial image with size (150x225).